# What is written on Minato's cloak?

Tags: naruto, japanese-language

I searched for what is written on Minato's cloak and I found different answers.

[image]

What does it really mean?

Comment: Just curious, but what answers you have found?

Answer (score 3):

**It's 四代目火影 (*Yondaime Hokage*, lit. "Fourth Fire Shadow")** since Minato was the 4th Hokage of Konohagakure.

Comment: While technically correct, a bit of nuance is lost in a direct literal translation of "hokage". The word itself can mean either firelight, a flicker of light, in particular from a latern/lamp, or the shadow or form that move in firelight, like the flicker of light from a fire. The word holds a bit of symbolic meaning not unlike hitokage (lit. Human shadow) can refer to the soul.

Comment: @кяαzєя thanks for letting me know. I was following the [Wikia](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Minato_Namikaze)'s translation.

Comment: Just take note not to be overly reliant on them. They are at best tertiary sources. Do your own research when possible.